# Setting up database in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'm currently stuck on creating a SQL Server database in Visual Studio. I went to server explorer, created a database called `UserData.mdf`. Then I created a table to store `usernames` and `passwords`. I named the table `LOGIN` and stored a `username` called `Faculty_ID` and a `password` called `pass123` I stored both as a `Varchar(50)` datatype. Everything was fine until I had to write the code for my login button.

Here's the code snippet that is giving me an error:

> SqlDataAdapter("Select Count (*) From dbo.[LOGIN] where Username='" + USERNAME_txt.Text + "' and Password ='" + password_txt.Text + "'", con);

where it says:

> The name Username/password does not exist in the current context

What should I rename or change?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace LOGINPAGE
{
    public partial class Room : Form
    {
        public Room()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Hide();
            FloorSelection ss = new FloorSelection();
            ss.Show();
        }

        private void EXIT_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }

        private void xButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Mohamed\Documents\UserData.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30");
            this.Hide();

            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("Select Count (*) From dbo.[LOGIN] where username='" + username_txt.Text + "' and Password ='" + password_txt.Text + "'", con);

            FloorSelection ss = new FloorSelection();
            ss.Show();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `where Username='" + USERNAME_txt.Text + "'` Please don't do this. You open yourself up to SQL injection attacks. Learn about parameterized SQL.

Comment: Injection attacks? I'm only making a sample login program for testing purposes.

Comment: @InfiniteProgrammer - even for testing, it's still wise to use good practises so you don't reinforce bad habits on yourself. Nevertheless, your variables you're using are likely misspelled or out of scope. Step through your code and make sure they are what you expect them to be.

Comment: Here's my table T-SQL

Comment: `CREATE TABLE [dbo].[LOGIN] (
    [USERNAME] VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    [PASSWORD] VARCHAR (50) NULL, 
    CONSTRAINT [PK_LOGIN] PRIMARY KEY ([USERNAME])
);
`

Answer (score 0):

Would recommend always put the a forms values into variable and never reading them from the form directly into a query, even for tests, otherwise you end up with a very tightly coupled test.

Have you tried this approach?

```
void FillLogins(string userName, string password)
    // Open connection
    using (SqlConnection c = new SqlConnection(yourConnectionString))
    {
    c.Open();
    // Create new DataAdapter / Command
    using (SqlDataAdapter a = new SqlDataAdapter(
        "Select Count (*) From dbo.[LOGIN] where Username= @userName AND Password = @password", c))
      {
        a.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userName", userName);
        a.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", password);
        // Use DataAdapter to fill DataTable
        DataTable t = new DataTable();
        a.Fill(t);
      }
   }
}
```

Then you can call it like this (assuming you are not using databinding)

```
FillLogins(USERNAME_txt.Text, password_txt.Text);
```

Comment: How do I implement a passwordChar to hide the password characters?

Comment: Technically that is a completely different question to what you have asked above, but you can find the info here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/system.windows.forms.textbox.passwordchar(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I resolved my issue. It seems the textboxes I was calling were named differently than what I thought. Thank you!